# Where did I go wrong in this function in c?

Tags: c

I need to implement this function:

> Check availability (allows the user to specify a type of armchair
> (SPACE, BALCONY, GALLERY) and prints a message on the screen
> indicating whether armchairs of the specified type are available. And
> the output should be: integer which reports the first available seat
> for the indicated armchair type. -1 if no places of the type indicated
> are available. Returns the first available seat for the indicated seat
> type or -1.

The problem is that when I start the program the output is:

```
1. Show Room Status
2. Check Availability
0. Exit
2
Enter seating type to reserve
(0=Stall 1=Balcony 2=Gallery): 0
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_SEATS 20
#define FIRST_STALL 0
#define LAST_STALL 9
#define FIRST_BALCONY 10
#define LAST_BALCONY 14
#define FIRST_GALLERY 15
#define LAST_GALLERY 19

typedef enum {
    STALL,
    BALCONY,
    GALLERY
} SeatingType;

char type[3][20] = {"Stall", "Balcony", "Gallery"}; // 3 are the words and 19 are the characters for each word + the null character

typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    char email[20];
    int seat_number;
    SeatingType seat_type;
} Reservation;

typedef struct {
    bool available;
} Seats;

void show_room_status(Seats seats[MAX_SEATS]) {
    for(int i = FIRST_STALL; i <= LAST_STALL; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Stall: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Stall: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
    for(int i = FIRST_BALCONY; i <= LAST_BALCONY; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Balcony: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Balcony: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
    for(int i = FIRST_GALLERY; i <= LAST_GALLERY; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Gallery: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Gallery: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
}

int check_availability(Seats seats[MAX_SEATS], Reservation reservation[MAX_SEATS]) {
    do {
        printf("Enter seating type to reserve\n(0=Stall 1=Balcony 2=Gallery): ");
        scanf("%d", &reservation->seat_type);
    } while(reservation->seat_type > 2 || reservation->seat_type < 0);
    switch (reservation->seat_type) {
        case 0:
            for(int i = FIRST_STALL; i <= LAST_STALL; i++) {
                if(seats[i].available == false) {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;

        case 1:
            for(int i = FIRST_BALCONY; i <= LAST_BALCONY; i++) {
                if(seats[i].available == false) {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;

        case 2:
            for(int i = FIRST_GALLERY; i <= LAST_GALLERY; i++) {
                if(seats[i].available == false) {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    Reservation reservation[MAX_SEATS];
    Seats seats[MAX_SEATS];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SEATS; i++) {
        seats[i].available = false;
    }
    int choice;
    do {
        printf("\n---------------\n");
        printf("1. Show Room Status\n");
        printf("2. Check Availability\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                show_room_status(seats);
                break;
            case 2:
                check_availability(seats, reservation);
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Choice!\n");
                break;
        }
    } while(choice != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know where I went wrong, pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function, but not using its return value.
Added a variable available_seats and printed it after the function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_SEATS 20
#define FIRST_STALL 0
#define LAST_STALL 9
#define FIRST_BALCONY 10
#define LAST_BALCONY 14
#define FIRST_GALLERY 15
#define LAST_GALLERY 19

typedef enum {
    STALL,
    BALCONY,
    GALLERY
} SeatingType;

char type[3][20] = {"Stall", "Balcony", "Gallery"}; // 3 are the words and 19 are the characters for each word + the null character

typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    char email[20];
    int seat_number;
    SeatingType seat_type;
} Reservation;

typedef struct {
    char available;
} Seats;

void show_room_status(Seats seats[MAX_SEATS]) {
    for(int i = FIRST_STALL; i <= LAST_STALL; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Stall: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Stall: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
    for(int i = FIRST_BALCONY; i <= LAST_BALCONY; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Balcony: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Balcony: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
    for(int i = FIRST_GALLERY; i <= LAST_GALLERY; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Gallery: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Gallery: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
}

int check_availability(Seats seats[MAX_SEATS], Reservation reservation[MAX_SEATS]) {
    do {
        printf("Enter seating type to reserve\n(0=Stall 1=Balcony 2=Gallery): ");
        scanf("%d", &reservation->seat_type);
    } while(reservation->seat_type > 2 || reservation->seat_type < 0);
    switch (reservation->seat_type) {
        case 0:
            for(int i = FIRST_STALL; i <= LAST_STALL; i++) {
                if(seats[i].available == false) {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;

        case 1:
            for(int i = FIRST_BALCONY; i <= LAST_BALCONY; i++) {
                if(seats[i].available == false) {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;

        case 2:
            for(int i = FIRST_GALLERY; i <= LAST_GALLERY; i++) {
                if(seats[i].available == false) {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    Reservation reservation[MAX_SEATS];
    Seats seats[MAX_SEATS];
    int available_seats;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SEATS; i++) {
        seats[i].available = false;
    }
    int choice;
    do {
        printf("\n---------------\n");
        printf("1. Show Room Status\n");
        printf("2. Check Availability\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                show_room_status(seats);
                break;
            case 2:
                available_seats=check_availability(seats, reservation);
                printf("Available seats = %d",available_seats);
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Choice!\n");
                break;
        }
    } while(choice != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to guess what is the problem, as you have not written, what is actually wrong with your program.

I originally thought, that your would like to reserve seats once some is requested. Then you should insert

```
seats[i].available = TRUE;
```

into check_availability three times, just before `return i+1;`

Otherwise, you can just copy the code from the three places in `show_room_status` and insert it at the same places. For example:

```
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Stall: [OCCUPIED]\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Stall: [AVAILABLE]\n", i + 1);
        }
```

Also `available` is specifying, whether a seat isn't available. I would find that confusing. Consider naming it reserved, or swap the values.

Are you intending to count the seats continuously? Otherwise you should subtract the base index of each group:

```
    for(int i = FIRST_GALLERY; i <= LAST_GALLERY; i++) {
        if(seats[i].available == true) {
            printf("%d. Gallery: [OCCUPIED]\n", i - FIRST_GALLERY + 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d. Gallery: [AVAILABLE]\n", i - FIRST_GALLERY + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question isn't about reserving seats, it's about the `check_availability()` function that displays whether a seat is available.

Comment: What is wrong with it? For me it's working fine?

Comment: There's no `printf()` in `check_availability()` that prints the output described in the question. How does your change fix that?

Comment: I thought ```show_room_status``` was for seeing the result of a reservation.

Comment: Read the first 2 lines of the question: "I need to implement this function: Check availability". The question is about option 2, not option 1.

Comment: Yes, option 1 is working, but option 2 isn't reserving anything, which is why option 1 can't display the reservation.

Comment: Option 2 isn't supposed to reserve anything. It just checks whether the chair is available and prints a message to that effect.